# print map values in descending order in c++

Tags: c++

I have a map input which contains a list of words and their counts.

I use this function to print the `map` input:

```
template <class KTy, class Ty>
void PrintMap(map<KTy, Ty> map)
{
    typedef std::map<KTy, Ty>::iterator iterator;
    for (iterator p = map.begin(); p != map.end(); p++)
        cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;
}
```

it prints the values likes this:

`you : 296
she : 14
go : 29`

how can I print it in descending order of word count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// Copy it into a vector.
std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> vector( map.begin(), map.end() );

// Sort the vector according to the word count in descending order.
std::sort( vector.begin(), vector.end(), 
           []( const auto & lhs, const auto & rhs ) 
           { return lhs.second > rhs.second; } );

// Print out the vector.
for ( const auto & item : vector )
    std::cout << item.first << ": " << item.second << std::endl;
```

The map is sorted according to the keys, i. e. alphabetically. You cannot change that behaviour. Therefore, the easiest way to get the job done is copying it into a vector and sorting it with a user defined compare function.

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: @MurhafSousli Fixed it. Now it's descending.

Answer (score 3):

`map` stores elements sorted by `key` not by value. Unless you want to change the type of your map, the only way to do it is to sort your elements after getting them out. I think the easiest way to do so is via [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Given that dereferencing an iterator into a `map` gives a `const value_type&`, we can take advantage of the reference to avoid actually creating copies of `value_type` (which is a `std::pair<Key, Value>`). However, the code will be a little longer than if we wanted to copy:

```
template <class KTy, class Ty>
void PrintMap(const std::map<KTy, Ty>& map)
{
    using vt = const typename std::map<KTy, Ty>::value_type*;
    std::vector<vt> vec(map.size());
    size_t i = 0;
    for(const auto& keyval : map)
    {
        vec[i++] = &keyval;
    }
    std::sort(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [](vt _lhs, vt _rhs){return _lhs->second > _rhs->second;});

    for(const auto& el : vec)
        std::cout << el->first << ": " << el->second << std::endl;
}
```

With a test

```
std::map<std::string, int> myMap{{"you", 296}, {"she", 14}, {"go", 29}};
PrintMap(myMap);
```

Outputs

> you: 296
>
> go: 29
>
> she: 14

This should be much faster if your map is of non-trivially copyable elements.

Comment: I would like to print them according to the count value, can you update your answer with some code?

Comment: @MurhafSousli: Sorry, got pulled away. Updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Put data in another container, sort by word count, print.

Comment: or use boost::multi_index